# NestList on a function of several arguments

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'd like to know if it is possible to use `NestList` on a regular function of several arguments, such as:

```
fc[x_, y_] := {x + y, x - y};
res = NestList[ fc[x,y], {100, 75}, 50]
```

I just started learning *Mathematica* at my university, read about pure functions, but from the homework's text it doesn't look like I should use that. Roughly translated, it would be "*Define a function of 2 arguments (...) and apply `NestList` on this function.*"

Comment: I discussed a similar example [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node509.html),may possibly be relevant as another illustration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way to deal with "multiple inputs" to a function like NestList is to express the many inputs as a single vector. For example:

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {x + y, x - y};
NestList[f, {100, 75}, 5]
```

does what you are looking for

```
{{100, 75}, {175, 25}, {200, 150}, {350, 50}, {400, 300}, {700, 100}}
```

Comment: I didn't know I could specify arguments of the function in such manner. Neat. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

I suggest to look at this :

```
fc[x_, y_] := {x + y, x - y}
NestList[fc @@ # &, {100, 75}, 5]
```

> ```
> {{100, 75}, {175, 25}, {200, 150}, {350, 50}, {400, 300}, {700, 100}}
> ```

First, after `SetDelayed` (`:=`) you don't have to use `;`, look at `CompoundExpression`.
Second,  `fc` has to be applied (`Apply`) to the list of arguments.